# UIImageView+AFNetworking often (but not always) fails to load within a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, afnetworking, xcode4.6

UIImageView+AFNetworking has always worked ok in a UITableViewCell for me. Images used to load smartly while scrolling and rarely failed to load. Recently, it stopped working well. Has anyone else experienced this? Was this UIImageView category never intended to work inside of a UITableView?

A few details: my UIImageView is inside of a UITableViewCell in a Storyboard. I call `setImageWithURL:` from within the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

The problems seem to have started when switching to AFNetworking 1.0, specifically in conjunction with moving to Xcode 4.6 and building against iOS 6.1 SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), a perfect replacement for AFNetworking and perfectly compatible with iOS 6.1.

Comment: I also tried SDWebImage which DID work, but was not quite as simple as AsyncImageView, which also has built in cross-fade loading and an activity indicator. And, anecdotally, great performance.

Answer (score 0):

Switched to the AsyncImageView library, using it in exactly the same way (from within `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`), and I've had no problems since. Might be an AFNetworking + iOS 6.1 bug... Would love to know if anyone else has had similar problems.